# Embeded Linux device fails to get DHCP

Tags: linux, networking, dhcp

I'm trying to get an embedded Linux device to use DHCP to get it's IP. I think it is trying, this is from the boot output:

```
Configuring network interfaces: cat: can't open '/var/run/udhcpc.eth0.pid': No such file or directory
udhcpc (v1.15.3) started
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
Sending discover...
No lease, failing
failed
```

Earlier in the output there is also:

```
IP-Config: Guessing netmask 255.255.255.0
IP-Config: Complete:
     device=eth0, addr=192.168.0.1, mask=255.255.255.0, gw=255.255.255.255,
     host=192.168.0.1, domain=, nis-domain=(none),
     bootserver=255.255.255.255, rootserver=255.255.255.255, rootpath=
```

Which in not correct, the IP should be in 192.168.3.*.

I can get it to get an IP by running `udhcpc` and then unplugging and replugging the network cable, but that obviously isn't a solution.

Full Boot Output: http://pastebin.com/ztEDNrRR

Comment: The unwanted "192.168.0.1" IP address is being passed into the kernel on the *kernel command line*.  That text originates from the *bootargs* environment variable in U-Boot.  Perhaps you should revise that variable and remove that item.